# C++ operator overloading []

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

i have a little problem with my code in c++.. I need to doit this way, because it's work to school..

I have template named Catalog

```
template <typename T>
class Catalog
{
    struct Item{
        T* _product;
        unsigned int _amount;
        Item* _next = nullptr;
    };

    Item* _head;
    Item* _actual;
    Item* _last;

    int _size;
    void init()
    {
        this->_size = 0;
        this->_head = nullptr;
        this->_actual = nullptr;
    };
public:
    Catalog(void)
    {
        this->init();
    };

    T*& operator[](unsigned int){
        Item* node = this->_head;
        for (int i = 0; i < this->_size; i++)
        {
            if (i == pos)
            {
                return &node->_product;
            }
            node = node->_next;
        }
        return nullptr;
    };
};
```

It's a structure where i have Items and in Items i have pointer to next one in array..

I tryed to like this

```
Catalog<Products> *catalog = new Catalog<Products>();
Products *pr1 = new ProductA(5, "jmeno", 5);
catalog->Add(pr1, 5);
Products* ct = catalog[0];
```

In my case visual studio is reporting this error

```
IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from SemestralniPrace::Catalog<Products>" to "Products *" exists
```

I want to correct operator[] so i can use my catalog like i need to.. or correct the code in main..

It's for example, i have some more functions in class Catalog, but it isn't importnent for this problem..

Can someone help me please.. Even suggestions is good for me. I am desperate with this.

Thanks and sorry for my English, it's not mine native language.

Comment: `catalog` variable is a pointer, try `(*catalog)[0]` or try declaring it as `Catalog<Products> catalog;` instead (and doing `catalog.Add(pr1,t);`)

Comment: Oh, thanks, now it's working. I used (*catalog)[0].. I have few experience with c++, and it was only in school, so i can't figured out how to correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two mistakes. The first one is relative to the return statement of the `operator []`. The type of expression `&node->_product` is `T**` while the return type of the operator is  `T*&`

You have to write simply

```
return node->_product;
```

The second mistake is relative to statement

```
Products* ct = catalog[0];
```

You have to write either

```
Products* ct = ( *catalog )[0];
```

or

```
Products* ct = catalog[0][0];
```